# .on("ready") define guild id with mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, discord.js

I trying to code a simple customize statistic with command trought data base "mysql" and i have problem about define guildID in "Ready" function is the anyway to define it or i need search other solutions

```
const Discord = require("discord.js")
const { bot } = require('../index');
const { mysql } = require('../index')

bot.on('ready', async () => {
  setInterval(function() {
    let sql = 'SELECT * FROM stats WHERE guildID = ?'
    mysql.query(sql, [guild.id], (err, results) => {
      let allchannels = results.channelID
      let guildid = results.guildID
      setInterval(() => {
        const guild = bot.guild.get(`${guildid}`)
        var userCount = guild.memberCount;
        const totalUsers = bot.channels.get(`${allchannels}`)
        totalUsers.setName(`total members = ${userCount}`)
      }, 20000);
      })    
  }, 15000);
})
```

> connection.query(sql, [guild.id], (err, results) => {
>   ReferenceError: guild is not defined

i want to code a statistic like StartIT v4 bot but idk is it possible in ready? i dont want on any restart my bot use command like !start statistic etc,
im glad if someone know how to fix it or have any solution

Answer (score 0):

You problem is that guild is not defined, the bot Object has no `guild` only `guilds` a Collection where all guilds are listed. You can either fetch the id of the specific server and filter the collection, or what i think is better for your case loop throw the hole collection and set the statistics.

As for if its possisble, you can use bot.on `guildCreate` and `guildDelete` to listen when a bot joines a new server or leaves a server. I dont know what values you want to have in your statistics, but if you want an overview above all servers your bot is running on i would use the create and delete event.

Here you can see that the client (your bot) has no attribute `guild`
[discord.js Client](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client)

Comment: i have on bot.on(guildCreate) inster into guildID to mysql but idk how to define specific channel.id for server like when i have 50 servers and every server use my statistic //sry english btw

Comment: so you want the statistics of all of your 50 servers in one channle on your server?

Comment: no. one server can use statistic from his server like server xyz has 10 guild members they have channel named "guild members 10", i know i can do this with .on("message") but i dont want on any bot restart using command like !statistic start etc and i trying to use it in ("ready") and define guild.id + channel.id from mysql